# Do "a joint sprain" and "a joint displacement" mean the same thing?

Tags: terminology

[According to Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/sprain), "sprain" means

> an injury to a joint (= a place where two bones are connected) caused by a sudden movement

Do "a joint sprain" and "a joint displacement" mean the same thing?

Comment: Where have you seen "joint displacement" used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be referring to "joint dislocation", instead of "joint displacement", which in my understanding would mean removal of the joint (at which point the two terms asked about obviously will not have anything in common).

As for sprain versus dislocation: In a sprain the bone endings making up the joint are moved out of their natural placement ("distorsion") with ligament injury ("sprain"), but do return to their natural placement afterwards (i. e. with the right configuration of communicating bone endings facing each other).

In a dislocation the moving out of place happens as well, but the bone endings do not move back to their natural configuration afterwards, meaning they luxated (joint dislocation is also called luxation).

You can read more about this here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_dislocation and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprain